# IIS not working after upgrade to Windows 10 Pro from Windows 7 Unlimited

Tags: iis

Today I upgraded my windows 7 ultimate to windows 10 pro. Every thing seems to work fine. But the localhost is now throwing error : HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I checked IIS, it is running. I checked the version of IIS from IIS Manager, it is showing Version 10.0.10240.16384.

I test my sites on localhost.

Before upgrade, in windows 7 ultimate it was working fine. I also checked "Turn windows feature on or off" and found that IIS is installed properly.

Please guide me.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer / windows logs to see if there is a specific error that is being thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Joe Raio for providing the hint. I checked the event log and found that rewrite.dll was causing error. I uninstalled IIS URL rewrite extension and the problem is gone. Now everything is working as before, classic asp, php, everything.

Comment: It's worth noting that you uninstall from "Programs and Features" and then reinstall from: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite . Works fine again afterwards.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. The concerning thing is that this happened to me when upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10, then again when upgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 10 Pro. So it leads me to believe that there is a bug in their major upgrades that breaks the IIS rewrite module every time. I hope someone from Microsoft sees this and fixes before the next major upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution

Go to the Application Pool ...
Advanced Settings ...
Process Model ...
Identity ...
Set it to "LocalSystem"